Firebase messaging notifications from node.js admin sdk not delivered (or shown) to iOS device
I am experiencing issues in notifications sent to an iOS device from Firebase. The client app is made using flutter.
The notifications are sent from a node.js cloud function using the admin-firebase package. The notificationPayload is formed for both notification and data fields. The method used to send the messages is send and I am using the FCMtoken read from the flutter FirebaseMessaging library which I stored in firestore for every user when they entered the app. I am allowing until 5 FCMtokens for user just in case they log in to many devices, so send will reach to all devices where the user has logged up.
That is my function:
//Attempt to send an identic message (title, body) to every token in fcmTokens
//fcmTokens is an array of objects and assume that the variable token indeed holds the valid //token for each iteration
function sendNotifications(fcmTokens, userId, payloadData, title, body, silent = false) {
  // Customize the notification payload
  try {
    Object.entries(fcmTokens).forEach(async (entry) => {
      const key = entry[0];
      const token = entry[1];
      console.log(`Key: ${key} - Token: ${token}`);

      notificationPayload = {
        token: token,
      };
      if (payloadData) {
        notificationPayload.data = payloadData;
      }

      // Add notification body if it's not a silent notification
      if (!silent) {
        notificationPayload.notification = {
          title: title,
          body: body,
          content_available: true
        };
      } else {
        console.log("Silent notification.");
      }
      const messaging = admin.messaging();
      
      await messaging.send(notificationPayload)
      .then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        //console.log(`Notificationpayload: ${JSON.stringify(notificationPayload)}`);
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
      })
      .catch(async (error) => {
        console.error('Error sending message:', error);
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error building notification payload: ${error}`);
    return null; // Handle the error as needed
  }
}

Tokens are stored in firestore on key-pair value map for abling the cloud function to get these values.  So every time the cloud function is sending a notification it first reads the necessary tokens from firestore.
The issue is that I am able to receive notifications in android (both in foreground and background, and even silent ones without the notification) but not in iOS (not foreground nor background). What I am sure is that the FCMtoken is successfully read and stoerd in Firestore because I see the firestore document being updated when I log in on an iOS device. The curious thing is that I manually picked the FCMtoken from firestore and used the test send message button in Cloud messaging section on the firebase web console and I succesffully received the test notification in the iOS device.
Is there an extra configuration I need to do in the iOS app itself or do I need to add more stuff to the payload?
UPDATE
I ran the app in debug mode in an iOS physical device and I see this:

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
Exception: Invalid argument(s): iOS settings must be set when
targeting iOS platform.
#0      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:151:9)
#1      NotificationControllerFree._configureLocalNotifications (package:resistentes/notification_controller_free.dart:48:44)
#2      NotificationControllerFree.initializeRemoteNotifications (package:resistentes/notification_controller_free.dart:41:11)


So I am going to update the flutter local notifications initialization and let's see if I managed to get something else.
UPDATE 2
I followed @jasonph suggestions and I added the local notifications initialization specific for IOs and I am now receiving the notifications.
But still some tricky details not working as expected. If app is in foreground, I know I am receiving the notification because I see my notification controller handling it on the debug console but no notification is displayed. If app is in background, the notification is displayed but I don't see the notification controller handling it on the debug console.
What else am I missing?
I'm also seeing this in the console when the app initializes. I don't know if it might be related:

[FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications
proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If
you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add
"FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to
NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.


have you added APN key

Yes, I did it was working a few months ago and the thing that the test message from the firebase web console is working let me think that is not related with APN key, because in the end without the proper APN key I wouldn't be able to reach the device no matter where I am sending the message from...

Have you added the serviceAccountKey.json file to your server?

Yes servieAccountKey.json is added, notifications are being sent correctly, since I receive them in Android and web enviornments, the issue is only on iOS

In that case, it would be helpful if you could provide your flutter implementation.

Make sure you request permission to receive notifications on iOS. Based on the logs you provided, I am assuming you are using the flutter_local_notifications package. Check this guideline from the package provider and follow it to request permission.
Regarding the issue in your UPDATE, I am suspecting the cause is at the initialization step which should look something like the below code:
final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin, // this must be added for targeting iOS
    macOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
    linux: initializationSettingsLinux);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse);


That helped me a lot, I am receiving now the notifications. But still some tricky details not working as expected. If app is in foreground, I know I am receiving the notification because I see my notification controller handling it on the debug console but no notification is displayed. If app is in background, the notification is displayed but I don't see the notification controller handling it on the debug console.

Hi, this issue might be helpful https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/2196
